# XSL - For each and If loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to run a transform on an XML to produce an output that does not include certain elements from the source based on attribute values.

Being a beginner i'm having a bit of a problem working out the for each and if loop.

Source XML:

```
<manifest xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/f4m/1.0"><id>TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAP</id>
<duration>39.960</duration>
<mimeType>video/f4v</mimeType>
<streamType>recorded</streamType>
<bootstrapInfo id="PV4" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA88AAAAAIAAAAAAAA9QAAAJxAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo>
<bootstrapInfo id="PV5" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA88AAAAAIAAAAAAAA9QAAAJxAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo
<bootstrapInfo id="PV8" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA88AAAAAIAAAAAAAA9QAAAJxAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo>
<bootstrapInfo id="PV10" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA88AAAAAIAAAAAAAA9QAAAJxAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo>
<bootstrapInfo id="PV13" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAnAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA6NAAAAAIAAAAAAAA6IAAAKjAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo>
<bootstrapInfo id="PV14" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAnAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA6NAAAAAIAAAAAAAA6IAAAKjAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo>
<bootstrapInfo id="PA3" profile="named">AAAAe2Fic3QAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm9UAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAANWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAACAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAnEAAAAAQAAAAAAAB1gAAAJkgA</bootstrapInfo>
<media streamId="PV4" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV4" bitrate="351" width="384" height="216" bootstrapInfoId="PV4">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXUo9cKPXCgAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAWQAAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQDUAAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PV5" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV5" bitrate="226" width="512" height="288" bootstrapInfoId="PV5">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXUo9cKPXCgAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAU0AAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQD4AAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PV8" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV8" bitrate="661" width="704" height="396" bootstrapInfoId="PV8">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXUo9cKPXCgAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAU0AAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQD4AAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PV10" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV10" bitrate="1269" width="960" height="540" bootstrapInfoId="PV10">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXUo9cKPXCgAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAU0AAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQD8AAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PV13" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV13" bitrate="2222" width="960" height="540" bootstrapInfoId="PV13">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXRcKPXCj1wAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAWQAAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQD8AAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PV14" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV14" bitrate="3970" width="1280" height="720" bootstrapInfoId="PV14">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXRcKPXCj1wAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAWQAAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQEAAAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PA3" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPA3" bitrate="47" bootstrapInfoId="PA3">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAWQYUeuFHrgAMYXVkaW9jb2RlY2lkAgAEbXA0YQAGYWFjYW90AAAAAAAAAAAAAA9hdWRpb3NhbXBsZXJhdGUAQOdwAAAAAAAADWF1ZGlvY2hhbm5lbHMAQAAAAAAAAAAACXRyYWNraW5mbwoAAAABAwAGbGVuZ3RoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAl0aW1lc2NhbGUAQI9AAAAAAAAACGxhbmd1YWdlAgADZW5nAAAJAAAJ</metadata>
</media>
</manifest>
```

I am looking at producing an output xml containing the relevant bootstrap and media nodes where the following attributes are present, PV4, PV5, PV8, PV10 and PA3

here's my XSL so far.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:f4m="http://ns.adobe.com/f4m/1.0" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<manifest xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/f4m/1.0">
<id>
<xsl:value-of select="/f4m:manifest/f4m:id[1]/text()"/>
</id>
<duration>
<xsl:value-of select="/f4m:manifest/f4m:duration[1]/text()"/>
</duration>
<mimeType>
<xsl:value-of select="/f4m:manifest/f4m:mimeType[1]/text()"/>
</mimeType>
<streamType>
<xsl:value-of select="/f4m:manifest/f4m:streamType[1]/text()"/>
</streamType>
</manifest>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

expected output:

```
<manifest xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/f4m/1.0">

<id>TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAP</id>
<duration>39.960</duration>
<mimeType>video/f4v</mimeType>
<streamType>recorded</streamType>
<bootstrapInfo id="PV4" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA88AAAAAIAAAAAAAA9QAAAJxAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo>
<bootstrapInfo id="PV5" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA88AAAAAIAAAAAAAA9QAAAJxAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo
<bootstrapInfo id="PV8" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA88AAAAAIAAAAAAAA9QAAAJxAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo>
<bootstrapInfo id="PV10" profile="named">AAAAm2Fic3QAAAAAAAAABAAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAAVWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAAEAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAA88AAAAAIAAAAAAAA9QAAAJxAAAAADAAAAAAAAZFAAACd0AAAABAAAAAAAAIwAAAAQBAA=</bootstrapInfo>
<bootstrapInfo id="PA3" profile="named">AAAAe2Fic3QAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAPoAAAAAAAAm9UAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAABlhc3J0AAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAQBAAAANWFmcnQAAAAAAAAD6AAAAAACAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAnEAAAAAQAAAAAAAB1gAAAJkgA</bootstrapInfo>
<media streamId="PV4" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV4" bitrate="351" width="384" height="216" bootstrapInfoId="PV4">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXUo9cKPXCgAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAWQAAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQDUAAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PV5" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV5" bitrate="226" width="512" height="288" bootstrapInfoId="PV5">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXUo9cKPXCgAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAU0AAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQD4AAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PV8" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV8" bitrate="661" width="704" height="396" bootstrapInfoId="PV8">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXUo9cKPXCgAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAU0AAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQD4AAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PV10" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPV10" bitrate="1269" width="960" height="540" bootstrapInfoId="PV10">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAXUo9cKPXCgAFd2lkdGgAAAAAAAAAAAAABmhlaWdodAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMdmlkZW9jb2RlY2lkAgAESDI2NAAKYXZjcHJvZmlsZQBAU0AAAAAAAAAIYXZjbGV2ZWwAQD8AAAAAAAAADnZpZGVvZnJhbWVyYXRlAP/4AAAAAAAAAAl0cmFja2luZm8KAAAAAQMABmxlbmd0aAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJdGltZXNjYWxlAECPQAAAAAAAAAhsYW5ndWFnZQIAA2VuZwAACQAACQ==</metadata>
</media>
<media streamId="PA3" url="TearsOfSteel_Teaser_1920x1080_2.0EN_25_XDCAM_REWRAPPA3" bitrate="47" bootstrapInfoId="PA3">
<metadata>AgAKb25NZXRhRGF0YQgAAAAAAAhkdXJhdGlvbgBAWQYUeuFHrgAMYXVkaW9jb2RlY2lkAgAEbXA0YQAGYWFjYW90AAAAAAAAAAAAAA9hdWRpb3NhbXBsZXJhdGUAQOdwAAAAAAAADWF1ZGlvY2hhbm5lbHMAQAAAAAAAAAAACXRyYWNraW5mbwoAAAABAwAGbGVuZ3RoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAl0aW1lc2NhbGUAQI9AAAAAAAAACGxhbmd1YWdlAgADZW5nAAAJAAAJ</metadata>
</media>
</manifest>
```

Any advice/assistance appreciated.

Comment: A task like this usually doesn't require a for-each loop and if-condition but would rather be solved using template matches. I don't have time for a full answer right now but will come back later.

Comment: Can you show the output you expect in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you are simply wanting to remove elements, the approach to take is usually to use the XSLT identity template, and add templates to match the elements you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks @TimC output i am expecting has been added to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking at producing an output xml containing the relevant
>   bootstrap and media nodes where the following attributes are present,
>   PV4, PV5, PV8, PV10 and PA3

AFAICT, this should do it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:f4m="http://ns.adobe.com/f4m/1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="f4m:bootstrapInfo[not(@id='PV4' or @id='PV5' or @id='PV8' or @id='PV10' or @id='PA3')]"/>
<xsl:template match="f4m:media[not(@streamId='PV4' or @streamId='PV5' or @streamId='PV8' or @streamId='PV10' or @streamId='PA3')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If i was to want to update the contents of the id node, how would i go about that with your solution @michael.hor257k? 

As the XSL is now copy all nodes (apart from the ones its not), i cant see where to split it.

Sorry if it's simple, but i'm still new to XSL

Comment: @azz2912 You would simply add another template matching `f4m:id` and place the relevant instructions there. The idea here is that the more specific templates override the default identity transform template.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k